# What is an adjective relating to the concept of dialects?

Tags: adjectives, modifier-vs-of

I'm trying to say:

> the dialect__ differences between Castilian and Chilean Spanish are
>   exciting.

I thought it was *dialectic*, but I recently found out that dialectic [meant](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dialectic?s=t):

> the art or practice of logical discussion as employed in investigating
>   the truth of a theory or opinion. logical argumentation.

Or does dialectic also make sense in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**dialectal**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dialectal); the third example is almost exactly the context you describe:

> *Dialectal differences between Canadian and American English were judged to be irrelevant for this research.*

---

I will say that I personally would use "the differences in dialect" or "between the Castilian and Chilean dialect of Spanish", before "dialectal". "dialectal differences" sounds pretty technical, but that may be what you are going for.

Comment: Simple noun compounds like _dialect differences_ are quite common and correct, as well. This goes along with _language differences, gender differences,_ etc.